# Javascript draw rectangulars depending on "real-time" events from Angularjs or WS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, canvas, drawing

Please have  a little patience with this!

I'm working on a real-time concurrent system that schedules tasks: there N "masters"(human operator) that can schedule different tasks that take X minutes(X depends on the tasks) to the M available workers (other humans). Each worker has an maximum 600 minutes a day period of work and can only execute one task at a point in time - in other words tasks do not overlap.

I'm trying to build a graphical point and click web interface for the "masters". 
Each "master" sees a M columns ( each column representing a worker ). I want to represent the occupied time of each worker with a red rectangle, with yellow the period of time another "master" has the intention of reserving but hasn't done yet  and with green the "free" time that a worker has.

I can pass messages really fast between "masters" - I use Angularjs with WebSockets that communicate with a Python bridge to a REDIS. I can do over 10000 messages in under a second. The real-time I was mentioning is in fact ONE SECOND.

My problem is drawing the rectangle and updating it's color. I'm using a canvas.
How can a make this three state ( red, yellow , green ) rectangle draw fast?! 
How can I do it without redrawing most of the canvas?!

Someone with experience can please give me some pointers, or at least tell me if it's impossible ....

Thanks in advance!

PS: 
As an interaction recipe I'm using this [Interacting with Canvas Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452791/interacting-with-canvas-rectangle).

Here is a simplified version of what I am doing : http://jsfiddle.net/jLpLL5ee/1/

```
<body ng-app="Crap">

<div ng-controller="ChckCtrl">
<div ng-click="didClicked($event)">
  <canvas   width="400" height="400" id="canvas1" ></canvas>
</div>

</div>


</body>
```

And the JS

```
var $scope;
(function(){

var app = angular.module("Crap", []);

 app.controller("ChckCtrl", function($scope){
            function  whereClicked(e) {
                            var x = e.offsetX,
                                y = e.offsetY;

                            for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++) {
                                if(x > rects[i][0]
                                && x < rects[i][0] + rects[i][2]
                                && y > rects[i][1]
                                && y < rects[i][1] + rects[i][3]) {
                                    alert('Rectangle ' + i + ' clicked');
                                    // here 
                                }
                            }
                     };

      $scope.didClicked = whereClicked;

      ///draw something
      var canv = document.getElementById("canvas1");
      var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');


      var rects = [[0, 0, 100, 100], [0, 150, 50, 100]];
      for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++) {
          if (i % 2 < 1 ){
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
          }
          else{
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(100,100,0)";
          }
          ctx.fillRect(rects[i][0],
                       rects[i][1],
                       rects[i][2],
                       rects[i][3]);
      }

 });

})();
```

Comment: how many active shapes do you have on the canvas?

Comment: Around 100, even more on a crowded day.

Comment: Aha... And you want to interact with each and every polygon?

Comment: Yes, I need to open a new interactive panel on click event only on the yellow and green - not the red. Any ideas?

Comment: update: I ended up by implementing my own drawing system on a canvas with Quadtrees to detect overlapping.